# Understanding the nature of psychological defense system by artificial intelligence

Tags: game-theory

Do you think [psychological defense system](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defence_mechanism), for example, repression, regression, reaction, formation, isolation, undoing, projection, introjection, sublimation, etc., could be created by artificial intelligence systems? Can AI also be used to better understand the psychological defense system?

If yes, what tools do we need? Maybe supervised learning algorithms, such as [PSO](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particle_swarm_optimization) or [ANN](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_neural_network), are better suited for these levels?

That doesn't seem to be that easy, and I think it needs to have a more general understanding of these algorithms. So I asked here.

On the other hand, what do you think is the appropriate workspace or workspace available for this job?

For example, I think the interactions between robots that use different levels of the defense system by our selection as a game theory round play, could be good and suited to the community which is equal to the psychological connection of this part of us and as a testing environment.

But the robots themselves are dealing with a real problem that makes it even more difficult, som according to this approach, by selecting a more nonlinear problem to solve we can count the using the levels of these defense mechanisms (for example, in simple problem 30% 1th level, 20% 2th level and ...).